# Can't find Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I'm trying to get Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel reference in my Visual Studio 2008 project but when i click on add reference button I just can add Microsoft.Office.Core. I really need that .dll to deal with an excel file. Is there any way i can get this reference?

Comment: Have you looked under the `.NET` tab in add reference?

Comment: Did your computer installed OFFICE?

Comment: Yes i have OFFICE installed and i did look under .NET tab as well. Under Visual Studio 2010 when i add the Microsoft Office Object Library i get the reference well but in Visual Studio 2008 i just get the Core reference.

Comment: Try to find at any below path, using And manually add reference to the project.. 

%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14
(or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14 on 64-bit operating systems)
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15
(or %ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office15 on 64-bit operating systems)

Comment: I somehow opened the excel file and tried to reload the reference and suddently it was there. Don't really get why it was not there since the begining.